# Using python subprocess.Popen to set iptables where proto is gre

Tags: python, iptables

I'm facing a weird issue. I am trying to do the following in the output chain of my mangle table

```
iptables -t mangle -D OUTPUT -p gre -d 2.2.2.0/24 -j MARK --set-mark <somemark>
```

When I execute the above command from shell, it goes though fine and adds above rule to the output chain in the mangle table.

However, when I am trying to achieve the same using the subprocess module, I do not get any error but the rule is not added in the output chain in the mangle table.

Code:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["iptables", "-t", "mangle", "-I",
                      "OUTPUT", "--dst", "2.2.2.0/24",
                      "-p", "gre", "-j", "MARK",
                      "--set-mark", "0x04"])
p.wait()
```

The other thing that is flipping me is that when I change the protocol to tcp/udp/esp it works fine. I face this ONLY when the protocol is gre. I tried using GRE, 47 and gre.

Could anyone please let me know what I am missing?

Just an update the same rule when I add to POSTROUTING chain, it gets added. I am not sure what is so special about adding proto 47 to OUTPUT chain?

Comment: You are missing a `]` from the looks of it, unless its a copy-paste error.

Comment: My bad. That's a copy-past error.